# drawRect not called with setNeedsDisplay

Tags: cocoa

my ui structure is like NSWindow -> NSViewController -> NSView(parent) -> NSView(target view).
the target view is dragged from XIB file, rather than `addSubview`. The `drawRect` function will be called when the NSView(parent) is shown, but after that i want to call drawRect again programmatically with `setNeedsDisplay`, it doesn't work.
What's wrong with my method?

Anyway, i can use drawRect(view.frame) to implement this, but i think this is not a good idea.

Code:

```
MyView.m

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSLog(@"asasa");
}

...
@property (weak) IBOutlet MyView *titleBarView;
...

-(IBAction)test:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view.subviews); // contains the titleBarView
    NSLog(@"%@",self.titleBarView); // not nil
    [self.titleBarView setNeedsDisplay:YES]; // not call drawRect
}
```

titleBarView is already connected

Comment: do you call `setNeedsDisplay` of target view?

Comment: @bluedome, yes, i called setNeedsDisplay but it doesn't work

Comment: Show the code which calls `setNeedsDisplay:`. Also, are you sure you're calling it on the view you think you are? Which view is that, the parent or the target? Could it be that your reference to that view is `nil` because you didn't connect something (e.g. an outlet) properly? Never call `drawRect`; it won't work right.

Comment: @KenThomases, please check my updates

Comment: i can use `[self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES]` to call drawRect of the NSView(Parent)

Comment: When you say "contains the titleBarView" in the comment, you're actually comparing the logged instance address (0x…) with the instance that's logged in the next line, right? You haven't just looked for your custom subclass name, have you? I wonder if you accidentally have two different instances of your title bar view class, one in the view hierarchy and one not, and the outlet is connected to one which isn't in the window's view hierarchy.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `drawRect`?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing now will trigger `drawRect:` of `self.titleBarView`, but not `self.view`. To trigger the `drawRect:` of `self.view` (the one with the `NSLog` statement), call `setNeedsDisplay` on `self.view`.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];

NSLog(@"asasa");
}

...
@property (weak) IBOutlet MyView *titleBarView;
...

-(IBAction)test:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view.subviews); // contains the titleBarView
    NSLog(@"%@",self.titleBarView); // not nil
    [self.titleBarView setNeedsDisplay:YES]; // this triggers the drawRect: method of self.titleBarView
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES]; // this triggers your drawRect: method with he NSLog statement
}
```

Comment: The problem is the `[self.titleBarView setNeedsDisplay:YES]` doesn't call drawRect: method of self.titleBarView

Comment: Oh. Hm. Are you sure self.titleBarView was added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: i found the root cause that i used  `CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];` `self.layer = gradientLayer;` in drawRect function, but i don't know why this code cause this issue